# Library is found by ldconfig but not by ldd for any program using this library

Tags: arch-linux, dynamic-linking, shared-library, arch-arm

Running arch linux, I have qt5-base installed, which provides libQt5Core.so.5.

Running ldconfig finds the shared object:

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libQt5Core
libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.10.0
```

but when I run ldd on programs requiring libQt5Core.so, it is not found. Trying to start these programs fails:

```
$ ldd $(which keepassx) | grep libQt5Core
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found

$ ldd /usr/lib/notepadqq/notepadqq-bin | grep libQt5Core
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

`/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so` is a symlink to `libQt5Core.so.5.10.0` which has the following `file` output:

```
/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.10.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=4da280cdc46f7f0e4f257556e2ecc6b2eb31afa3, for GNU/Linux 3.17.0, stripped
```

The file output for keepassx is:

```
 $ file $(which keepassx) /usr/lib/notepadqq/notepadqq-bin: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=8fafc88639032c270fd9d4c153720dc33db44823, stripped
```

I've tried re-installing `qt5-core` and doing full system upgrades, but neither help. How can I fix my system so that programs requiring libQt5Core.so can be run?

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be a packaging problem with qt5-base in the arch linux arm repo: https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=12396